# Checking the value of a URL in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a program where there is an if condition testing a URL containing specific text but I am getting an error.

```
Sub test()

Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
Dim srlnum As String
Dim wb As WebBrowser

Set sht = Sheets("sheet1")
RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Serial No"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Expiry Date"


Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
Do While counter >= 1

    RowCount = RowCount + 1


    'srlnum = InputBox("Enter Serial Number")
    srlnum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & RowCount).Value

    With objIE
    .Visible = True

search:

   .navigate "http://tallysolutions.com/tallyweb/modules/crm/accounts/intranet/CLicenseFilterCtlr.php?strInvoker=wcc&strSearchClick=yes&strCalledFromLoginMenu=1"

    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set serialnum = .document.getElementById("strInputProdSerial")
    serialnum.Value = srlnum
    .document.getElementById("btnShow").Click

    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    On Error GoTo search

    If objIE.Url.toString.contains("http://tallysolutions.com/tallyweb/modules/crm/accounts/intranet/CSiteAdvanceSearchListCtlr.php") Then
    Stop
    End If

    For Each ele In .document.all
         Select Case ele.ID
                Case "trLicenseInfoContainer"

                      sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = srlnum
                      sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innerText

        End Select
    Next ele


     End With
     wb.Quit
     Set wb = Nothing

  counter = counter + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

The line

```
If objIE.Url.toString.contains("http://tallysolutions.com/tallyweb/modules/crm/accounts/intranet/CSiteAdvanceSearchListCtlr.php") Then
```

returns an error stating `the object does not support this property or method`, but I don't know what this error means.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "blog" it is a questions and answers site, as such, *specific refined* questions are needed, can you expand on: *"is there any other way to write this code"*?

Comment: The original post invited the StackOverflow community to rewrite the supplied code by mistake, and this was confusing some people. This question in fact has a very simple answer that does not require a rewrite at all, so there is no reason for people to complain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LocationURL, not Url.

> **LocationURL** Gets the URL of the resource that is currently displayed.

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: hey thanks but it gives an error as invalid qualifier